# Is there a way to get the canned ACL of an existing S3 object?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy an existing object from one key to another in the same bucket.

I'd like to get the canned ACL e.g.  "private"|"public-read"|"public-read-write"|"authenticated-read"|"aws-exec-read"|"bucket-owner-read"|"bucket-owner-full-control" so that I can then apply this to the new object.

What's the best way to do this using the Node.js SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`getObjectAcl()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObjectAcl-property) to obtain the ACL on the source object, and then specify that information using `putObjectAcl()`, or even specify it as part of the `copyObject()` call.

You won't get the "canned ACL", but you will get the permissions on the object that were created as a result of the original Canned ACL.

Comment: Thanks John Rotenstein.

You say it can be use ACL directly in `copyObject` but I can only see a way to send the canned ACL?

Comment: There are some (rather confusing) `GrantRead` type permissions available on the `copyObject()` command that can probably be used, but I don't see how they directly map to the information returned by `getObjectAcl()`, so it's probably easier to call `putObjectAcl` after copying the object. FYI, the use of ACLs is being [phased-out](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-s3-object-ownership-simplify-access-management-data-s3/) with a new capability of buckets to ignore ACLs. It is generally better to use a Bucket Policy, but they don't go down to the object-level.